# Sell different products on a single page

Tags: cart, products, bundled-product, grouped-products, addtocart

I have to create a single page that needs to show various type of products (simple, grouped and bundle) and they have to be added to the cart.

In addition to this I cannot set a "add to cart" button for every product, but I have to use only one "add to cart" button that works for all the products in the page.

Is it possible? Anyone could guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a very elegant way to sell multiple products, why not combine them all as a bundle product?

If you really don't want to, you can simply have your add button perform the following logic:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
foreach ($products as $product){
    $qty = 1; //or your desired qty
    $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
}
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```